# Col plot in r shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to recreate a barchart that I made in R with shiny, but i'm having some issue.

The plot should display the date on the x axis and a number on the y axis (In my case a total number of passengers passed trough an airport).

The data looks like this:

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~Aeroporto, ~Nazionali, ~Internazionali, ~Transiti.diretti, ~Totale.Commerciale, ~Aviazione.Generale.e.altri, ~TOTALE,    ~file_name,  ~anno, ~mese,        ~data,
   "Trieste",      28922,           16426,                 0,               45348,                          89,   45437, "2019_01.xls", "2019",  "01", "2019-01-01",
   "Trieste",      29231,           18161,                 4,               47396,                         113,   47509, "2019_02.xls", "2019",  "02", "2019-02-01",
   "Trieste",      36580,           23653,                 2,               60235,                         157,   60392, "2019_03.xls", "2019",  "03", "2019-03-01",
   "Trieste",      38717,           24880,               165,               63762,                         175,   63937, "2019_04.xls", "2019",  "04", "2019-04-01",
   "Trieste",      43082,           32089,               100,               75271,                         237,   75508, "2019_05.xls", "2019",  "05", "2019-05-01",
   "Trieste",      43959,           33324,               135,               77418,                         262,   77680, "2019_06.xls", "2019",  "06", "2019-06-01",
   "Trieste",      37934,           37260,               343,               75537,                         336,   75873, "2019_07.xls", "2019",  "07", "2019-07-01",
   "Trieste",      30200,           33016,                39,               63255,                         202,   63457, "2019_08.xls", "2019",  "08", "2019-08-01",
   "Trieste",      36514,           39343,               272,               76129,                         253,   76382, "2019_09.xls", "2019",  "09", "2019-09-01",
   "Trieste",      43330,           38978,                 9,               82317,                         186,   82503, "2019_10.xls", "2019",  "10", "2019-10-01",
   "Trieste",      37940,           21179,                 2,               59121,                         140,   59261, "2019_11.xls", "2019",  "11", "2019-11-01",
   "Trieste",      35464,           19663,                 6,               55133,                         107,   55240, "2019_12.xls", "2019",  "12", "2019-12-01",
   "Trieste",      31117,           19068,                 1,               50186,                         126,   50312, "2020_01.xls", "2020",  "01", "2020-01-01",
   "Trieste",      27979,           17102,                60,               45141,                          75,   45216, "2020_02.xls", "2020",  "02", "2020-02-01",
   "Trieste",       5377,            3725,                 0,                9102,                          31,    9133, "2020_03.xls", "2020",  "03", "2020-03-01",
   "Trieste",          0,               0,                 0,                   0,                           0,       0, "2020_04.xls", "2020",  "04", "2020-04-01",
   "Trieste",          0,               0,                 0,                   0,                           0,       0, "2020_05.xls", "2020",  "05", "2020-05-01",
   "Trieste",       2172,               0,                 1,                2173,                          83,    2256, "2020_06.xls", "2020",  "06", "2020-06-01",
   "Trieste",      12381,            2911,                98,               15390,                         157,   15547, "2020_07.xls", "2020",  "07", "2020-07-01",
   "Trieste",      15631,            5106,                55,               20792,                         136,   20928, "2020_08.xls", "2020",  "08", "2020-08-01",
   "Trieste",      18685,            2186,               428,               21299,                         229,   21528, "2020_09.xls", "2020",  "09", "2020-09-01",
   "Trieste",      19439,            2424,               175,               22038,                         122,   22160, "2020_10.xls", "2020",  "10", "2020-10-01",
   "Trieste",       8827,             851,               274,                9952,                          64,   10016, "2020_11.xls", "2020",  "11", "2020-11-01",
   "Trieste",      10696,             976,               258,               11930,                          89,   12019, "2020_12.xls", "2020",  "12", "2020-12-01",
   "Trieste",       7282,             883,               184,                8349,                          86,    8435, "2021_01.xls", "2021",  "01", "2021-01-01",
   "Trieste",       3527,             181,                15,                3723,                          67,    3790, "2021_02.xls", "2021",  "02", "2021-02-01",
   "Trieste",       4803,             464,                80,                5347,                          39,    5386, "2021_03.xls", "2021",  "03", "2021-03-01",
   "Trieste",      10347,             324,               147,               10818,                         105,   10923, "2021_04.xls", "2021",  "04", "2021-04-01",
   "Trieste",      18600,             223,                53,               18876,                         136,   19012, "2021_05.xls", "2021",  "05", "2021-05-01",
   "Trieste",      29532,            4458,                72,               34062,                         226,   34288, "2021_06.xls", "2021",  "06", "2021-06-01",
   "Trieste",      35398,            8755,               125,               44278,                         274,   44552, "2021_07.xls", "2021",  "07", "2021-07-01",
   "Trieste",      36785,           12216,                96,               49097,                         251,   49348, "2021_08.xls", "2021",  "08", "2021-08-01",
   "Trieste",      30198,           13106,                18,               43322,                         197,   43519, "2021_09.xls", "2021",  "09", "2021-09-01",
   "Trieste",      32589,           13030,               171,               45790,                         304,   46094, "2021_10.xls", "2021",  "10", "2021-10-01",
   "Trieste",      29997,           11758,                11,               41766,                         187,   41953, "2021_11.xls", "2021",  "11", "2021-11-01",
   "Trieste",      30685,           10726,                 2,               41413,                          97,   41510, "2021_12.xls", "2021",  "12", "2021-12-01",
   "Trieste",      20192,            5910,                16,               26118,                         118,   26236, "2022_01.xls", "2022",  "01", "2022-01-01",
   "Trieste",      21141,            6047,                 0,               27188,                          93,   27281, "2022_02.xls", "2022",  "02", "2022-02-01"
  )
```

This is the code I used to create my plot in R:

```
ggplot(data = eda_trieste_airport) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = data, y = TOTALE, fill = anno)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(dmy("16-03-2020")), 
             color = "black", size = 1)
```

The plot created is like this:

[image]

Now I would like to reproduce the plot in a `shiny` app but I'm running in issues.

The code so far is this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Exploratory Data Analysis of Trieste Airport"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(
        inputId = "year",
        label = "Anno",
        choices = unique(eda_trieste_airport$anno),
        selected = unique(eda_trieste_airport$anno)
      )
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("colPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  eda_reactive <- reactive({
    req(input$year)
    eda_trieste_airport <- eda_trieste_airport %>% filter(anno == input$year)
  })
  output$colPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate a col plot
    ggplot(data = eda_reactive()) +
      geom_col(aes(x = data, y = TOTALE, fill = anno)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(dmy("16-03-2020")), color = "black", size = 1) +
      labs(
        x = "Data",
        y = "Totale passeggeri"
      )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Basically, I would like the plot to change whenever I select the years I'm interested in.

If I select a single year, the plot is right but when I select all the years to show, the plot is not like the one in R code.

[image]

Comment: perhaps you want `filter(anno %in% input$year)`?

Comment: @Ben yes it worked!! Thank you very very much!
Just curious, do you know why filter(anno == input$year) doesn't work while your solution does?

Comment: You are comparing two vectors of different lengths. If you use `==` you are comparing elementwise the two vectors and recycling, which is not what you want. Instead, using `%in%` you are instead looking for each element in the first vector that matches an element in the second vector. Try in your console examples such as `1:3 == 2:4` (all false, comparing 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4) and `1:3 %in% 2:4` (1 not matched, but 2 and 3 do match). Let me know if this helps.